# ASP.NET application error when run in Win Server 2008 64-bit

Tags: asp.net, excel, windows-server-2008, dcom, network-service

May you help me, My ASP.NET application can't import excel file when migrating this application that run in Win Server 2003 32-bit to the Win server 2008 64-bit environment.
How to fix this bug? because in Win Server 2003 32-bit, it runs properly.

the error report that appear is:
*System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad) at Admin_ImportRisk.CreateTempTable() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ERMApproval\Administrator\ImportRisk.aspx.vb:line 66.*

The code in line 66 of my application is:
oBooks.Open(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Risk.xls"))

I have tried several scenarios:

1. Added Network Service user to the Microsoft Excel Application in DCOM configuration and set the identity of Application pool that in used to be same.
2. Added all many kind of user to the Microsoft Excel Application and My computer in security of DCOM configuration. And I have added many kind of user too in the application's folder.
3. Used corflags.exe to force 32-bit application to run in 64-bit environment
4. Used regsvr32.exe to register a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll file to the windows 32-bit component services.
5. Used rundll32.exe to run the 32-bit Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll file in the 32-bit environment

But the result is still the same.
It will be a big honour if you can help me^^.
Best regards,
-imanuel-

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to compile your project to target x86 only.  This is a setting in the project settings.  So the .net framework will only generate a 32 bit application at runtime, rather than defaulting to 64 bit.  This is no different from setting corflags, however if you have multiple assemblies you ahve to make sure it's done for all of them. The application itself must target only 32 bit.

You're using a COM component that is 32 bit, and you can't do that in a 64 bit application, so force it to be 32 bit.

You can also force IIS to run it in the 32 bit context as documented here:

http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/

Also, make sure the 64 bit version of Excel is not installed on the server, but rather the 32 bit version.

Comment: Thx for the answer^^, but i have tried the link you gave last month. But it still no effect. Isn't that project setting only happen in desktop application? My application is a ASP.NET web application so there is no project setting can be set. For further information, i have set my Application pool that used by my application to run in 32-bit environment, but it's still the same